# In the slickgrid, unable to copy the cell value using context menu which is stored as either object or an array of objects in the data context

Tags: contextmenu, angular-slickgrid

1. I tried to copy a cell value, which is stored as an object or an array in the data context, but the copy menu was disabled.[image]
2. This is my dataContext:-

   ```
   {
       "display_name": "EMP1",
       "guid": "gpLT3ZZTZEfJsWZ",
       "pfm_148414_1708708_id": 2,
       "pfm_148426_id": 1,
       "pfm_6_1708718_id": null,
       "pfm_8_1708720_id": null,
       "pfm8_1708720": null,
       "approvalstatus": "A",
       "contactnumber": 234567890,
       "couch_id": null,
       "couch_rev_id": null,
       "createdby": 7285,
       "createdon": 1703139317459,
       "currencyvalue": 22,
       "decimalvalue": 77.96,
       "dob": 1701648000000,
       "doj": 1702276200000,
       "employeebatch": "B2",
       "employeemailid": "emp@gmail.com",
       "employeename": "Dhamu",
       "formulaboolean": null,
       "formulacurrency": null,
       "formuladate": null,
       "formuladatetime": null,
       "formulanumber": null,
       "formulastring": null,
       "hobbies": [
           "D",
           "DD"
       ],
       "isactive": false,
       "lastmodifiedby": 24005,
       "lastmodifiedon": 1703567680832,
       "name": "EMP1",
       "pfm148414_1708708": {
           "display_name": "2",
           "guid": "y5eVhDVsL5ywebn",
           "pfm_148414_id": 2,
           "pfm_6_1708608_id": 8368,
           "pfm_8_1708610_id": 4073,
           "pfm8_1708610": "17E99FA0-E527-23A6-BF0B-8BFAF70DD584",
           "costininr": null,
           "couch_id": null,
           "couch_rev_id": null,
           "createdby": 7285,
           "createdon": 1703139196085,
           "decimalvalue": null,
           "developermailaddress": "hp@gmail.com",
           "exporttocountries": [
               "I"
           ],
           "formulaboolean": null,
           "formulacurrency": null,
           "formuladate": null,
           "formuladatetime": null,
           "formulanumber": null,
           "formulastring": null,
           "govtapproved": "N",
           "isactive": false,
           "lastmodifiedby": 7285,
           "lastmodifiedon": 1703139196085,
           "manufaturercountry": "U",
           "productdescription": "Slimmest AMOLED display",
           "productid": "2",
           "productiondate": 1702339200000,
           "productiontime": 1702535400000,
           "productlink1": "{\"urlType\":\"single\",\"urlDBValue\":{\"displayValue\":\"www.azus.com\",\"urlValue\":\"www.azus.com\"}}",
           "productlink2": "{\"urlType\":\"multiple\",\"urlDBValue\":[{\"displayValue\":\"www.azus.com\",\"urlValue\":\"www.azus.com\"},{\"displayValue\":\"www.azus.com\",\"urlValue\":\"www.azus.com\"}]}",
           "productname": "HP laptops",
           "productnumber": 313132343,
           "producttiers": [
               "t3"
           ],
           "randomnumber": "2",
           "pfm6_1708608": "D30AF2BF-7571-8CCD-A3AA-8B397C905C3D",
           "type": "pfm148414",
           "sync_flag": "C",
           "org_id": 2,
           "id": "6B5C6A52-58E5-4635-B9D9-9AD3482062D1",
           "rev": "2-4e495ea178f7d836994b598930d4e4f1",
           "formulanumber__f": 2023,
           "formulastring__f": "DECEMBER",
           "formulaboolean__f": true,
           "formuladate__f": 1703548800000,
           "formuladatetime__f": 1703128020000,
           "formulacurrency__f": 88.98989,
           "cspfm_formula_fetch_status__s": "completed"
       },
       "productrating": "3",
       "qualification": [
           "10th",
           "MD"
       ],
       "randomnumber": "1",
       "roledescription": "Nil",
       "rollupboolean": null,
       "rollupcurrency": null,
       "rollupdate": null,
       "rollupdatetime": null,
       "rollupnumber": null,
       "rollupstring": null,
       "pfm6_1708718": "32158CEC-BAC8-188F-A792-F94DF1D768A0",
       "type": "pfm148426",
       "sync_flag": "C",
       "org_id": 2,
       "id": "F2AE46BB-D1CB-446E-B09C-D2DA50DDD1D1",
       "rev": "11-1cdb72321230e6ecac044c9743d2f0a4",
       "pfm149317s": [
           {
               "display_name": "1",
               "guid": "Ka5sqgWQLt9OFKm",
               "pfm_148414_1719333_id": 2,
               "pfm_148426_id": 1,
               "pfm_149317_id": 1,
               "address": "Erode",
               "pfm148426": "F2AE46BB-D1CB-446E-B09C-D2DA50DDD1D1",
               "couch_id": null,
               "couch_rev_id": null,
               "createdby": 24005,
               "createdon": 1703683137158,
               "dateofbirth": 1703635200000,
               "datetime": 1703745000000,
               "firstname": "Tamil Bro",
               "lastmodifiedby": 24005,
               "lastmodifiedon": 1703739327326,
               "pfm148414_1719333": {
                   "display_name": "1",
                   "guid": "ygrN5YjhRCPmA8O",
                   "pfm_148414_id": 1,
                   "pfm_6_1708608_id": 5902,
                   "pfm_8_1708610_id": 4073,
                   "pfm8_1708610": "17E99FA0-E527-23A6-BF0B-8BFAF70DD584",
                   "costininr": 20000,
                   "couch_id": null,
                   "couch_rev_id": null,
                   "createdby": 7285,
                   "createdon": 1703139054845,
                   "decimalvalue": 32,
                   "developermailaddress": "DEv@gmail.com",
                   "exporttocountries": [
                       "I",
                       "J",
                       "U",
                       "M"
                   ],
                   "formulaboolean": null,
                   "formulacurrency": null,
                   "formuladate": null,
                   "formuladatetime": null,
                   "formulanumber": null,
                   "formulastring": null,
                   "govtapproved": "Y",
                   "isactive": true,
                   "lastmodifiedby": 7285,
                   "lastmodifiedon": 1703139054845,
                   "manufaturercountry": "I",
                   "productdescription": "Laptop",
                   "productid": "1",
                   "productiondate": 1701648000000,
                   "productiontime": 1701671400000,
                   "productlink1": "{\"urlType\":\"single\",\"urlDBValue\":{\"displayValue\":\"azus\",\"urlValue\":\"www.azus.com\"}}",
                   "productlink2": "{\"urlType\":\"multiple\",\"urlDBValue\":[{\"displayValue\":\"www.azus.com\",\"urlValue\":\"www.azus.com\"}]}",
                   "productname": "AZUS",
                   "productnumber": 19829209,
                   "producttiers": [
                       "t2"
                   ],
                   "randomnumber": "1",
                   "pfm6_1708608": "4C77ABD9-6B69-56F1-8A7E-1D8DECFFFB0C",
                   "type": "pfm148414",
                   "sync_flag": "C",
                   "org_id": 2,
                   "id": "E14CCD7B-ADD9-4746-BB15-3375CE2DFA88",
                   "rev": "2-f8f5c63b9de8475e15bc9d91880b8a1d",
                   "formulanumber__f": 2023,
                   "formulastring__f": "DECEMBER",
                   "formulaboolean__f": true,
                   "formuladate__f": 1703548800000,
                   "formuladatetime__f": 1703128020000,
                   "formulacurrency__f": 88.98989,
                   "cspfm_formula_fetch_status__s": "completed"
               },
               "mailaddress": "tamil@gmail.com",
               "name": "1",
               "type": "pfm149317",
               "sync_flag": "C",
               "org_id": 2,
               "id": "28432DD9-47AD-484B-997A-ED04AFE79754",
               "rev": "3-89b3fa20fa16384af4ba2f1f3bc37378",
               "pfm149358s": [
                   {
                       "display_name": "1",
                       "guid": "e8Y3QNVMsK7Gtx0",
                       "pfm_148414_1719848_id": 2,
                       "pfm_149317_id": 1,
                       "pfm_149358_id": 1,
                       "couch_id": null,
                       "couch_rev_id": null,
                       "createdby": 24005,
                       "createdon": 1703683178829,
                       "description": "None",
                       "dob": 1703635200000,
                       "emailaddress": "example@gmail.com",
                       "firstname": "venkat",
                       "lastmodifiedby": 24005,
                       "lastmodifiedon": 1703683178829,
                       "pfm148414_1719848": {
                           "display_name": "2",
                           "guid": "y5eVhDVsL5ywebn",
                           "pfm_148414_id": 2,
                           "pfm_6_1708608_id": 8368,
                           "pfm_8_1708610_id": 4073,
                           "pfm8_1708610": "17E99FA0-E527-23A6-BF0B-8BFAF70DD584",
                           "costininr": null,
                           "couch_id": null,
                           "couch_rev_id": null,
                           "createdby": 7285,
                           "createdon": 1703139196085,
                           "decimalvalue": null,
                           "developermailaddress": "hp@gmail.com",
                           "exporttocountries": [
                               "I"
                           ],
                           "formulaboolean": null,
                           "formulacurrency": null,
                           "formuladate": null,
                           "formuladatetime": null,
                           "formulanumber": null,
                           "formulastring": null,
                           "govtapproved": "N",
                           "isactive": false,
                           "lastmodifiedby": 7285,
                           "lastmodifiedon": 1703139196085,
                           "manufaturercountry": "U",
                           "productdescription": "Slimmest AMOLED display",
                           "productid": "2",
                           "productiondate": 1702339200000,
                           "productiontime": 1702535400000,
                           "productlink1": "{\"urlType\":\"single\",\"urlDBValue\":{\"displayValue\":\"www.azus.com\",\"urlValue\":\"www.azus.com\"}}",
                           "productlink2": "{\"urlType\":\"multiple\",\"urlDBValue\":[{\"displayValue\":\"www.azus.com\",\"urlValue\":\"www.azus.com\"},{\"displayValue\":\"www.azus.com\",\"urlValue\":\"www.azus.com\"}]}",
                           "productname": "HP laptops",
                           "productnumber": 313132343,
                           "producttiers": [
                               "t3"
                           ],
                           "randomnumber": "2",
                           "pfm6_1708608": "D30AF2BF-7571-8CCD-A3AA-8B397C905C3D",
                           "type": "pfm148414",
                           "sync_flag": "C",
                           "org_id": 2,
                           "id": "6B5C6A52-58E5-4635-B9D9-9AD3482062D1",
                           "rev": "2-4e495ea178f7d836994b598930d4e4f1",
                           "formulanumber__f": 2023,
                           "formulastring__f": "DECEMBER",
                           "formulaboolean__f": true,
                           "formuladate__f": 1703548800000,
                           "formuladatetime__f": 1703128020000,
                           "formulacurrency__f": 88.98989,
                           "cspfm_formula_fetch_status__s": "completed"
                       },
                       "pfm149317": "28432DD9-47AD-484B-997A-ED04AFE79754",
                       "name": "1",
                       "type": "pfm149358",
                       "sync_flag": "C",
                       "org_id": 2,
                       "id": "68E3B4D1-818D-4672-AD83-0261D33FD5DF",
                       "rev": "2-655b2d062b818fe341d04a82ee5b75b8"
                   }
               ],
               "cspfm_pfm149358s_fetch_status__s": "completed"
           }
       ],
       "dob__s": "2023-12-04",
       "doj__s": "2023-12-11T06:30:00.000Z",
       "productrating__s": "contextparentobj.productrating.Option.Average",
       "approvalstatus__s": "contextparentobj.approvalstatus.Option.Approve",
       "employeebatch__s": "contextparentobj.employeebatch.Option.Batch 2",
       "qualification__s": "contextparentobj.qualification.Option.10th, contextparentobj.qualification.Option.Master's degree",
       "hobbies__s": "contextparentobj.hobbies.Option.Dancing, contextparentobj.hobbies.Option.Drawing",
       "formuladate__f__s": "2023-12-05",
       "formuladatetime__f__s": "2023-12-27T16:23:00.000Z",
       "rollupdate__r__s": null,
       "rollupdatetime__r__s": null,
       "r1__s": null,
       "rollupnumber__r": null,
       "rollupstring__r": "ok",
       "rollupboolean__r": false,
       "rollupdate__r": null,
       "rollupdatetime__r": null,
       "rollupcurrency__r": null,
       "cspfm_rollup_fetch_status__s": "completed",
       "formulanumber__f": 78,
       "formulastring__f": "venkat",
       "formulaboolean__f": false,
       "formuladate__f": 1701734400000,
       "formuladatetime__f": 1703694180000,
       "formulacurrency__f": 88.89,
       "cspfm_formula_fetch_status__s": "completed",
       "r5-contextlookupobj": [],
       "r2-contextlookupobj": [],
       "r3-contextlookupobj": [],
       "r2__s": ["1"],
       "r4-contextlookupobj": [],
       "cspfm_pfm149317s_fetch_status__s": "completed",
       "pfm149317s.0.firstname": true
   }
   ```
3. Here is the field name in the column definition

   args.grid.getColumns()[args.cell]['field']
   'pfm149317s.0.firstname'

Expecting to allow copying of the cell values either stored as an object or an array in the data context

Comment: the Copy feature from the context menu only works with a known structure and this doesn't look like a known structure from the column definitions (which you did not provide in your question). You could, and should, also troubleshoot it yourself, the code to enable the copy is shown in the ContextMenu [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/slickgrid-universal/blob/ca8e6a40d352c4f3025632eab79098c47943631b/packages/common/src/extensions/slickContextMenu.ts#L175-L188)